# Liferay 6:Eqvalinet code of JavaScript for Alloy UI

Tags: liferay-6

```
<portlet:actionURL  name="addBook" var="addBookURL" />



public void addBook(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException {

}
```

Hi , This is my Alloy UI Code for calling my MVCPortlet's Action class addBook Method .

My question is , I dont want to use Alloy UI in My UI , but pure JavaScript / Jquery .

So Is it possible to have equaveleint code for this in  pure JavaScript ??

```
<aui:form action="<%= addBookURL.toString() %>" method="post">

    <aui:input type="text" name="name"></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="password" name="pwd"></aui:input>
    <aui:button type="submit"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

Comment: On a sidenote, the `.toString()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this function you can use pure html, something like this:

```
<form name="<%= addBookURL.toString() %>" action="<%= addBookURL.toString() %>" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    <input type="password" name="pwd"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```